# Google Places API: rankby Distance Search

Tags: android, google-places-api

So I am using Google Places API with the `rankby distance` parameter and I get results, the thing is, I'm using it to get hospitals and it returns hospitals but only in a `10km` radius (more and less), it should return in a `50km` radius like it says in the documentation.

If I use the radius parameter in a `50km` radius instead of the `rankby`, it will return a lot more hospitals just not in order.

So my position didn't change and I get fewer hospitals with the `rankby distance` parameter. How can I fix this? Has anyone had the same problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [places.nearbySearch did not return results within the fixed radius of 50000m when used with option rankBy:distance](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5892)

Comment: The documentation in my country gives me this URL "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/output?parameters" and it says the rankby parameter uses a fixed radius of 50km... I just want to get the results sorted by distance...

Comment: It's likely a bug. Google has not fixed the issue that I linked above.

Comment: I did read the english documentation and it uses nearbysearch, textsearch or radarsearch. How should I proceed? Report a bug? Thank you for your answer btw ;) I can sort by distance using a search by radius but thats losing performance not much anyway